# SVG not sitting inside a div/tab(li)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

Hello I'm currently trying to put a SVG element inside a div and for some reason it is outside the div.

```
<div id="Force Layout" class="tabcontent">    
  <div class="ui-widget">    
    <input id="search">
    <button type="button" id="searchButton" onclick="searchNode()">Search</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="releasenode(); ">Release</button>    
  </div>
  <script> document.body.style.zoom = 1.0 </script>
  <div style="width: 100%; overflow:visible;"> </div>                   
  <div style="width:820px;  margin-top:50px;">  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">    
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"> </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/fisheye.js?0.0.3"> </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src = "/Portfolio for Web design/index.js"> </script>
  </div> 
</div>
```

The result ends up:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP7xg.png]

The D3 is always visible, as if it sits outside any tab/div altogether

Comment: I don't see an SVG ... anywhere! Would you mind adding it?

Comment: Sorry, the SVG runs in the "                    <script type='text/javascript' src = "/Portfolio for Web design/index.js"> </script>

Comment: That's fine. However, you need to include the `CSS` for the SVG *and* the `JS` for the SVG (at least the part where it is created and added to the div) so that potential answerers have enough information to figure out the problem. :)

Answer (score 5):

Typically, I don't think you would add the d3.js javascript inside a div in the way you have shown. I'd expect to see code that looks more like this:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type='text/javascript' src = "/Portfolio for Web design/index.js"</script>
```

Then inside your script you might have a line that says something like:

```
d3.select("#container").append("svg");
```

I am guessing you are currently assuming that the script generates SVG that is automatically rendered inside your container div. This isn't the case though - you d3.js has to explicitly reference the div into which to add SVG.

Comment: Thanks alot bartel, originally I had 
d3.select("body").append("svg"); 

Feel so...inexperienced hah